# Form submit is submitting once then doubles each time after

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

So I built this plugin, and while testing it out everything worked well until I finally reached the `onSubmit` part of the plugin. What is happening is that the form will submit once successfully but then afterwards it seems to be doubling the amount of times it submits. I don't exactly know how this is happening hence why I am turning to you guys for assistance.

I have provided a demo form, the way the plugin operates with the form and the plugin itself. Since I"m not sure where it is coming from in the plugin I have provided the entirety of the source code. Let me know if there is anything else that is required for assistance.

**html**

```
<form id='test'>
    <div class='form-group'>
        <input type='text' id='data' class='form-control' />
    </div>
    <button type='submit' class='btn btn-default'>Submit</button>
</form>
```

**javascript**

```
    $(function(){
        $('#test').validator({
            controls:{
                data : {
                    validate : 'notEmpty'
                }
            },
            onSubmit : function(){
                alert("success");

                // destroy the instance
                $('#test').validator('destroy');

                // get the original options
                var options = $('#test').validator('getSettings');

                // re initialize the plugin for the form
                $('#test').validator(options);
            }
        });
    });
```

**validator.js**

```
(function($){
    var _defaults = null;
    // functions object where the validator functions are stored for use
    var functions = {
        notEmpty : function(value){
            return value && $.trim(value).length > 0;
        },
        required : function(value){
            return value && $.trim(value).length > 0;
        },
        isEmail : function(value){
            var check = true;
            if(value.length)
                check = /^([^@\s\t\n]+\@[\w\d]+\.[\w]{2,3}(\.[\w]{2})?)$/.test(value);
            return check;
        },
        isPhoneNumber : function(value){
            var check = true;
            if(value.length)
                check = /^(\d\-)?\(?\d{3}\)?[\-|\s]?\d{3}[\-|\s]?\d{4}$/.test(value);
            return check;
        }, 
        isNumber : function(value){
            var check = true;
            if(value.length)
                check = /^[+-]?\d+(\.\d+)?$/.test(value);
            return check;
        },
        isSSN : function(value){
            var check = true;
            if(value.length)
                check = /^\d{3}\-?\d{2}\-?\d{4}$/.test(value);
            return check;
        },
        isString : function(value){
            var check = true;
            if(value.length)
                check = /^\D+$/.test(value);
            return check;
        },
        isURL : function(value){
            var check = true;
            if(value.length)
                check = /^([http\:\/\/]+)?([a-zA-Z]+)?\.?[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.[a-zA-Z]+$/.test(value);
            return check;
        },
        isDateTime : function(value, regex){
            var check = true;
            if(regex == null){
                return true;
            }
            var regexChars = regex.split("");
            var pattern = "^";
            for(var i = 0; i < regexChars.length; i++){
                switch(regexChars[i]){
                    case "d" : 
                    case "j" :
                        pattern = pattern + "(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])";
                        break;
                    case "D":
                        pattern = pattern + "(Sun|Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat)";
                    case "l" :
                        pattern = pattern + "(Sunday|Monday|Tuesday|Wednesday|Thursday|Friday|Saturday)";
                        break;
                    case "F" :
                        pattern = pattern + "(January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December)";
                        break;
                    case "M" :
                        pattern = pattern + "(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)";
                        break;
                    case "m" :
                    case "n" :
                        pattern = pattern + "(0?[1-9]|1[012])";
                        break;
                    case "Y" :
                    case "y" :
                        pattern = pattern + "(19|20)?[\\d]+";
                        break;
                    case "a" :
                    case "A" :
                        pattern = pattern + "([AaPp][Mm])";
                        break;
                    case "g" :
                    case "G" :
                    case "h" :
                    case "H" :
                        pattern = pattern + "(0?[0-9]|1[012]|2[0123])";
                        break;
                    case "i" :
                    case "s" :
                        pattern = pattern + "([012345][0-9])";
                        break;
                    case "/" :
                        pattern = pattern + "[/]";
                        break;
                    case ":" :
                        pattern = pattern + "[:]";
                        break;
                    case "." : 
                        pattern = pattern + "[.]";
                        break;
                    case " " :
                        pattern = pattern + "[ ]";
                        break;
                    case "," :
                        pattern = pattern + "[,]";
                        break;
                    case "-" :
                        pattern = pattern + "[-]";
                        break;
                }
            }
            pattern = pattern+"$";

            pattern = new RegExp(pattern, 'i');

            if(value.length)
                check = pattern.test(value);
            return check;
        },
        groupNotEmpty : function(value){
            return value.length > 0;
        },
        isRoutingNumber : function(value){
            //run through each digit and calculate the total
            var n = 0;
            for(var i = 0; i < value.length; i += 3){
                n += parseInt(value.charAt(i), 10)*3 + parseInt(value.charAt(i+1), 10)*7 + parseInt(value.charAt(i+2), 10);
            }
            //if the resulting sum is an even multiple of ten (but not zero), the aba routing number is good
            if(n != 0 && n % 10 == 0){
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        },
        isMacAddress : function(value){
            var check = true;
            if(value.length){
                check = /^([0-9A-F]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9A-F]{2})$/.test(value);
            }
            return check;
        },
         isIPAddress : function(value){
            var check = true;
            if(value.length){
                check = /^(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$/.test(value);
            }
            return check;
        },
        validPassword : function(value, selector){
            var form = this.$form;
            var that = this;
            var check = false;
            var strength = 0;

            if(value.length >= 1){
                 strength = 4;   
            }
            // password mixins
            var passwordChars = value.split('');
            var count = 0; // keep track of the characters
            for(p in passwordChars){
                count++;
                if(count < 8){
                    strength += 5;
                }else if(count >= 8 && count < 20){
                    strength += 3;
                }else if(count >= 20){
                    strength += 2;
                }
                if(/[0-9]/.test(passwordChars[p])){
                    strength += 3;
                }
                if(/[a-z]/.test(passwordChars[p])){
                    strength += 1;
                }
                if(/[A-Z]/.test(passwordChars[p])){
                    strength += 2;
                }
                if(/[!$@#]/.test(passwordChars[p])){
                    strength += 4;
                }

            }
            var progressBarHolder = $(form).find(selector).closest('.form-group');
            var progressBar = $(progressBarHolder).find('.progress-bar');
            var progressBarValue = strength;
            if(strength < 50){
                $(progressBar).css({
                    'width' : progressBarValue+'%',
                    'background-color' : '#D9534F'
                });
                $(progressBar).html(progressBarValue+'%');
            }else if(strength >= 50 && strength < 80){
                $(progressBar).css({
                    'width' : progressBarValue+'%',
                    'background-color' : '#F0AD4E'
                });
                $(progressBar).html(progressBarValue+'%');
            }else if(strength >= 80 && strength <= 100){
                $(progressBar).css({
                    'width' : progressBarValue+'%',
                    'background-color' : '#5CB85C'
                });
                $(progressBar).html(progressBarValue+'%');
            }else if(strength > 100){
                $(progressBar).css({
                    'width' : '100%',
                    'background-color' : '#5CB85C'
                });
                $(progressBar).html('100%');
            }
            if(strength >= 6){
                check = true;
            }
            return check;
        },
        equalTo : function(value, selector){
            var form = this.$form;
            var check = false;
            var checkValue = $(form).find(selector).val();
            if(value.length){
                if(value === checkValue){
                    check = true;
                }
            }
            return check;
        },
        isCreditCard : function(value){
            var that = this;
            var check = false;
            var value = value.replace(/[ -]/g, '');
            var card_types = [
                {
                    name : 'amex',
                    pattern: /^3[47]/,
                    valid_length: [15]
                }, {
                    //diners_club_carte_blanche
                    name: 'dccb',
                    pattern: /^30[0-5]/,
                    valid_length: [14]
                }, {
                    //diners_club_international
                    name: 'dci',
                    pattern: /^36/,
                    valid_length: [14]
                }, {
                    name: 'jcb',
                    pattern: /^35(2[89]|[3-8][0-9])/,
                    valid_length: [16]
                }, {
                    name: 'laser',
                    pattern: /^(6304|670[69]|6771)/,
                    valid_length: [16, 17, 18, 19]
                }, {
                    //visa_electron
                    name: 'electron',
                    pattern: /^(4026|417500|4508|4844|491(3|7))/,
                    valid_length: [16]
                }, {
                    name: 'visa',
                    pattern: /^4/,
                    valid_length: [16]
                }, {
                    //mastercard
                    name: 'mc',
                    pattern: /^5[1-5]/,
                    valid_length: [16]
                }, {
                    name: 'maestro',
                    pattern: /^(5018|5020|5038|6304|6759|676[1-3])/,
                    valid_length: [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
                }, {
                    name: 'discover',
                    pattern: /^(6011|622(12[6-9]|1[3-9][0-9]|[2-8][0-9]{2}|9[0-1][0-9]|92[0-5]|64[4-9])|65)/,
                    valid_length: [16]
                }
            ];

            if(value.length){
                var exists = false;
                var matches = false;
                var validlength = false;
                var validLuhn = false;
                var cardname = "";
                that.setCreditCardImage(cardname);
                for(var name in card_types){
                    if(value.match(card_types[name].pattern)){
                        matches = true;
                    }
                    if(card_types[name].valid_length.indexOf(value.length) > -1){
                        validlength = true;
                    }
                    if(matches && validlength){
                        cardname = card_types[name].name.toLowerCase();
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(matches && validlength){
                    var digit, n, sum, j, len, ref1;
                    sum = 0;
                    ref1 = value.split('').reverse();
                    for(n = j = 0, len = ref1.length; j < len; n = ++j){
                        digit = ref1[n];
                        digit = +digit;
                        if(n % 2){
                            digit *= 2;
                            if(digit < 10){
                                sum += digit;
                            }else{
                                sum += digit - 9;
                            }
                        }else{
                            sum += digit;
                        }
                    }
                    if(sum % 10 === 0){
                        validLuhn = true;
                    }           
                }else{
                    return check;
                }
                if(matches && validlength && validLuhn){
                    check = true;
                    that.setCreditCardImage(cardname);
                    return check;
                }else{
                    that.setCreditCardImage();
                    return check;
                }
            }else{
                check = true;
                return check;
                that.setCreditCardImage();
            }

        },
        isZipCode : function(value){
            var check = true;
            if(value.length){
                check = /^\d{5}(?:[-\s]\d{4})?$/.test(value);
            }
            return check; 
        },
        isDependent : function(value, selector){
            var check = true;
            if(selector.length){
                if(selector.substring(0,1) === '_'){
                    selector = "[data-validator*=isDependent"+selector+"]";
                }
                if(!this.notEmpty(value)){
                    form.find(selector).each(function(){
                        if($(this).val() !== ''){
                            check = false;
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
            return check;
        },
        testRegex : function(value, regex){
            var check = true;
            var caret = regex.substring(0);
            var dollar = regex.substring(regex.length-1);
            if(caret != "^")
                regex = "^"+regex;
            if(dollar != "$")
                regex = regex+'$';
            if(value.length && regex.length){
                var pattern = new RegExp(regex, 'i');
                check = pattern.test(value);
            }
            return check;
        }
    };
    var selectors = [];
    // private function that sets the form control data-validator values
    var setControlData = function(selector, options){
        var validate = options.validate;
        var validations = "";
        if(Array.isArray(validate)){
            validations = validate.join("|");
        }else{
            validations = validate;
        }
        if(validations.indexOf('isDateTime') > -1 && typeof(options.dateFormat) != 'undefined' && typeof(options.dateFormat) == 'string'){
            validations = validations.replace(/isDateTime/g, 'isDateTime'+options.dateFormat);
        }
        if(validations.indexOf('equalTo') > -1 && typeof(options.equalTo) != 'undefined' && typeof(options.equalTo) == 'string'){
            validations = validations.replace(/equalTo/g, 'equalTo'+options.equalTo);
        }
        if(validations.indexOf('testRegex') > -1 && typeof(options.regex) != 'undefined' && typeof(options.regex) == 'string'){
            validations = validations.replace(/testRegex/g, 'testRegex'+options.regex);
        }
        $(selector).data('validator', validations);
    };

    // main function that validates the form itself
    var validator = function(selector){
            var rVal = true;
            var element = selector;
            var errors = 0;
            //check if there is a validator option for the specific input and that it has a value to it
            if($(element).data('validator')){

                // get the element type and split the pipe separated values into an array
                var value = null;
                var type = $(element).attr('type');
                var formGroup = null;
                if(type != "radio" && type != "checkbox"){
                    formGroup = $(element).closest('.form-group');
                    value = $(element).val();
                }else{
                    formGroup = $(element).closest('.form-group');
                    value = [];
                    $(formGroup).find('.radio, .checkbox, .radio-inline, .checkbox-inline').each(function(){
                        $(":checked", this).each(function(){
                            value.push($(this).val());
                        });
                    });
                }

                // check the .data('validator') string to account for interior pipes that may be used with regexes or selectors
                var validations = $(element).data('validator');
                validations = validations.replace(/\|\=/g, '%=');
                var holding = [];
                if(validations.indexOf('testRegex') > -1){
                    var hold = validations.substring(validations.indexOf('testRegex'), validations.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
                    holding.push(hold);
                    validations = validations.replace(hold, '');
                }
                validations = validations.replace("||", "|");
                validations = validations.split('|');
                validations = validations.concat(holding);
                for(var x in validations){
                    validations[x] = validations[x].replace('%=', '|=');
                }
                validations = validations.filter(function(n){return n != undefined && n != ""});
                for(var i = 0; i < validations.length; i++){
                    if(validations[i].indexOf('validPassword') !== -1){
                        var selector = validations[i].replace('validPassword', '');
                        !functions['validPassword'](value, selector) ? errors++ : null;
                    }else if(validations[i].indexOf('isDateTime') !== -1){
                        var regex = validations[i].replace('isDateTime', '');
                        !functions['isDateTime'](value, regex) ? errors++ : null;
                    }else if(validations[i].indexOf('equalTo') !== -1){
                        var selector = validations[i].replace('equalTo', '');
                        !functions['equalTo'](value, selector) ? errors++ : null;
                    }else if(validations[i].indexOf('isDependent') !== -1){
                        var selector = validations[i].replace('isDependent', '');
                        !functions['isDependent'](value, selector) ? errors++ : null;
                    }else if(validations[i].indexOf('testRegex') !== -1){
                        var regex = validations[i].replace('testRegex', '');
                        var regex = regex.substring(regex.indexOf('/')+1, regex.lastIndexOf('/'));
                        !functions['testRegex'](value, regex) ? errors++ : null;
                    }else{
                        !functions[validations[i]](value) ? errors++ : null;
                    }
                }
                if(errors > 0){
                    $(formGroup).addClass('has-error');
                }else{
                    $(formGroup).removeClass('has-error');
                }
                if(errors > 0) rVal = false;
            }else{
                formGroup = $(element).closest('.form-group');
                if(errors > 0){
                    $(formGroup).addClass('has-error');
                }else{
                    $(formGroup).removeClass('has-error');
                }
            }

            return rVal;
    };
    // object literal for the methods
    var methods = {
        // defining the individual methods inside of the literal
        init : function(options){

            // Repeat this process over each element in the selector
            return this.each(function(){
                var $this = $(this);
                var settings = options;
                _defaults = options;
                console.log(settings);
                // validation to make sure at least the bare minimum is supplied
                if(typeof(settings) == 'undefined'){
                    console.log("No options were supplied for this plugin. 'selectors' and 'onSubmit' are required. Please see documentation for assistance");
                    return false;
                }else if(typeof(settings.controls) != 'object'){
                    console.log("'selectors' must be an object");
                    return false;
                }else if(typeof(settings.onSubmit) != 'function'){
                    console.log("'onSubmit' is a callback function");
                    return false;
                }

                // if nothing else was wrong proceed to run the rest of the program here
                var controls = settings.controls;
                var bindInput = typeof settings.bindInput != 'undefined' && settings.bindInput != false ? true : false;
                var showErrorMessage = typeof settings.showErrorMessage != 'undefined' && settings.showErrorMessage != false ? true : false;

                for(var control in controls){
                    if(typeof controls[control] != 'object'){
                        console.log("controls."+control+" must be an object. Skipping this element");
                        continue;
                    }else if(typeof controls[control].validate == 'undefined'){
                        console.log("controls."+control+".validate must be defined");
                        continue;
                    }
                    $($this).find('input, textarea, select').each(function(){
                        if($(this).is('#'+control)){
                            setControlData('#'+control, controls[control]);
                            selectors.push('#'+control);    
                        }else if($(this).hasClass(control)){
                            setControlData('.'+control, controls[control]);
                            selectors.push('.'+control);
                        }
                    });
                }
                if(bindInput){
                    $($this).find('input, textarea, select').on('change keyup click select focus', function(){
                        for(var s in selectors){
                            validator(selectors[s]);
                        }
                    }); 
                }
                if(showErrorMessage){
                    $($this).prepend("<section id='errorAlert' class='form-group col-xs-12 hidden'><div class='alert alert-danger' ></div></section>");
                }
                // handle the form submission 
                $($this).submit(function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var errors = "";
                    var rVal = true;
                    for(selector in selectors){
                        if(!validator(selectors[selector])){
                            rVal = false;
                            if(showErrorMessage){
                                var pos = selectors.indexOf(selector);
                                var control = selectors[pos].replace(/[.#]/g, '');
                                if(typeof controls[control].errorMessage != "undefined" && typeof controls[control].errorMessage == 'string'){
                                    errors += "&bull; "+controls[control].errorMessage+"<br>";
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if(rVal){
                        if(showErrorMessage){
                            $('#errorAlert').addClass('hidden');
                        }
                        settings.onSubmit();
                    }else{
                        if(showErrorMessage){
                            $('#errorAlert').removeClass('hidden');
                            $('#errorAlert > div').html(errors);
                            $('html, body').animate({
                                scrollTop : $('#errorAlert').offset().top
                            }, 1000);
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        },
        checkControl : function(control, options){
            return this.each(function(){
                setControlData(control, options);
                validator(control);
                $(control).on('change keyup click select focus', function(){
                        validator(control);
                }); 
            });
        },
        clearControl : function(control){
            return this.each(function(){
                $(control).removeData('validator');
                $(control).off('change keyup click select focus');
                validator(control);             
            });
        },
        getSettings : function(){
            return _defaults;
        },
        destroy : function(){
            return this.each(function(){
                $(this).find('input, select, textarea').each(function(){
                    $(this).data('validator', '');
                    validator($(this));
                    $(this).removeData('validator');

                });
            });
        }
    }

    // the engine
    $.fn.validator = function(){

        // get the first argument passed if any
        var method = arguments[0];
        if(methods[method]){
            method = methods[method];
            arguments = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
        // if there was no argument or the argument is the default argument object then proceed to initialize
        }else if(typeof(method) == 'object' || !method){
            method = methods.init;
        }else {
            console.log("Method "+ method + " does not exist for this plugin");
            return this;
        }

        // return the result that is wanted based on what was passed in the initial arguments
        return method.apply(this, arguments);
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: your "destroy" method doesn't seem to be removing events.

Comment: explain futher please?

Comment: You bind events every time you call .init, and you're doing that every time you submit. but you never remove said events, so the submit event gets bound 1 time, then 2 times, then 4, 8, etc

Comment: by events you mean the `$(selector).on('focus keyup etc....');` and in order to fix I should do something like `$(selector).off('focus keyup etc...');`?

Comment: yse and yes. /10chars

Comment: That did not solve my error, while it does refresh everything nicely it still causes the form to submit multiple times, almost like it's duplicating the plugin instance and doing it exponentially... ugh this is so damn confusing!!!

Comment: Why do you need to destroy and re-initialize the validator?

Comment: because I basically need to reset the form after the `onSubmit` function so that it's a fresh start for anyone using it, unless you have a better way?

Comment: well, with this being a custom plugin, the sky's the limit. you could instead just have a method on the validator that resets the values and such.

Comment: Well that's fine but what if I have a hidden field. That was in of the initial problems was that it wouldn't reset hidden fields or fields that triggered only when only event occurred so then on submit everything would clear but that hidden field would remain as a failed case and caused the validation to fail.

Comment: Holy crap at @KevinB when you mentioned the resetting of the "values and such", that triggered a thought, after I remove all of the data instances, I just needed to simply clear the values for each after the "re-validation" in destroy, then since I store the selectors globally I just reprocess the private method 'setControlData' for each selector and grab its respective option, and hazzah! it's fixed. Since you did mention the values reset, if you want to submit it as an answer I'll give you the credit for it since it was your idea and throw you some love! Thank you so much for you time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By destroying and re-initializing the plugin every time, you're relying on the plugin properly unbinding all event handlers, and in this case it doesn't appear to be.

It would likely be easier to just give the plugin a method that resets data and values on the inputs, thus giving you a fresh form without having to re-init.